# How to disable SimpleTap on Thinkpad Edge e430

Tags: windows-7, performance, thinkpad

Recently,  I have bought a [Thinkpad Edge e430](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/laptop/thinkpad/thinkpad-edge/e430/). I find it good and enjoyable. But, there are so many preinstalled programs that I don't need, since I'm a student and not a small business. I want a computer without software that I don't use or need.

My question is: **how do I disable the SimpleTap application so that it never autolaunches again**?

I have looked in msconfig, could'not find it there.

Answer (score 3):

Simpletap is an add-on like Thinkvantage so it can be uninstalled through the Uninstall program in the Control Panel.

If you want to disable Simple Tap at boot. On my X61s, it seems like the Simple Tap program is associated with the TPHOTKEY program at start-up. So if you disable that program with Ccleaner or some other way, you will not have the Simple tap program activated at boot time - and also not having the Thinkpad hotkey active (if there is one at the Thinkpad Edge, I didn't see one at the pictures on the Lenovo site (see the link in the question))

Comment: Yeah, but I want to just make it stop auto launching when system starts, not uninstalling

Comment: ok, I found this discussion on Lenovo forums, see http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-SimpleTap-and-MultiTouch/How-are-you-launching-SimpleTap/td-p/521175, to me, it seems like SimpleTap is just like other programs so it should be possible to have launch on demand instead of at start-up. I tried it myself sometime ago, will experiment on my old X61s and report the result

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: Thanks for replies. No, I don't have a TPHOTKEY, so I guess I'll just uninstall it. By the way, if I format everything and install Windows 7 what are the MUST HAVE Thinkpad applications?